# Importing a function from a different folder for unit testing throws an error for an exterior function call

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing, tdd

I'm new to unit testing, learning with unittest. I'm trying to run a unit test from a file in a separate tests folder, using import to bring in the function I want to test. 
When I run the test, I get a FileNotFoundError. The error points to a file that the main.py file should open, but for the test, I'm only importing the function translate.

I've tried setting up an `__init__.py` file with `__all__ = ["translate"]` - no change.

Here's my file structure:

```
|
|--dictionary_app
|   |--main.py
|   |--data.json
|
|--tests
    |--integration
    |
    |--unit
        |--test_1.py
```

Code from main.py:

```
#Get data from a JSON file
data = json.load(open("data.json"))

    def translate(w):
        w = w.lower()
        if w in data:
            return data[w]
        elif w.capitalize() in data:
            return data[w.capitalize()]
        elif len(difflib.get_close_matches(w, data.keys())) > 0:
            yes_no = input("Did you mean {} instead? Enter Y if yes, or N if 
                no: ".format(difflib.get_close_matches(w, data.keys())[0]))
            if yes_no == "Y":
                return data[difflib.get_close_matches(w, data.keys())[0]]
            elif yes_no == "N":
                return "This word does not appear in the Archives."
            else:
                return "Query not understood."
        else:
            return "This word does not appear in the Archives."

    def main():
        #calls translate
```

This line in test.py produces the error:
`from dictionary_app.main import translate`

My results

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'data.json'

I didn't expect the import to pull in the line opening data.json.

Comment: Could you provide the code that trying to open *data.json*. I guess you are trying to use a hardcoded path (like "./data.json") which will be invalid from your tests.

Comment: Oh hey, thanks for catching that one. I've edited the initial post. The call to open data.json is in the second line of the sample code.

Answer (score 0):

By doing this `data = json.load(open("data.json"))`, you're assuming that the file *data.json* is in the current execution directory.

So, you need to be in the directory *dictionary_app* when you run your test.

A more convenient way to proceed is to resolve the path of data.json by using `__file__` to get the directory of your script.

For example:

```
import os
current_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
filename = os.path.join(current_dir, "data.json")
data = json.load(open(filename))
```